# É mais correto utilizar o conceito de Mestre-Detalhe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, view

Estou com uma situação que gostaria de utilizar a forma mais correta (elegante) de implementar. O cenário é o seguinte:

Estou construindo um sistema de HelpDesk onde os Tickets são armazenados em uma tabela (e consequentemente tem seu próprio Model) e as Evoluções do ticket são armazenadas em outra.

A implementação que estou fazendo é com C# utilizando MVC e Razor

Já fiz a `View`de listagem de tickets e ao clicar nela vou para uma outra que apresenta detalhes com informações do título, conteúdo, setor que registrou e usuário.

Gostaria de trazer junto com essa `View` de detalhes o histórico de evoluções (e até mesmo cadastrar novas evoluções referentes ao ticket) e é justamente nisso que eu estou tendo dificuldades (reunir numa única `View` informações da `model` ticket e da `model` evolucoes).

Abaixo estão as estruturas montadas para melhor entendimento:
MODELS

```
public class ticket
{
    [Key]
    public int id_ticket { get; set; }
    public int id_setor { get; set; }
    public int id_usuario { get; set; }
    public string assunto_ticket { get; set; }
    public string prioridade_ticket { get; set; }
    public string mensagem_ticket { get; set; }
    public DateTime data_ticket { get; set; }
    public string status_ticket { get; set; }
}


public class Evolucao
{
    [Key]
    public int id_evolucao { get; set; }
    public int id_ticket { get; set; }
    public int id_usuario { get; set; }
    public string texto_evolucao { get; set; }
    public DateTime data_evolucao { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: creio que falta fazer o relacionamento entre as models.
Tipo
no Evolucao
public virtual ticket id_ticket { get; set; }

Comment: outra sugestão utilize o padrão de nomes já padronizado para models. ao invés de id_evolucao o correto seria EvolucaoId
com isso não vai precisar usar [ForeignKey("id_ticket")] nas relações das models, nem o [Key] pois com a terminação Id ele já sabe que é Key

Answer (score 0):

Marcelo você pode usar ViewModel pattern.

No caso de usar informações de duas Models em uma mesma view você pode criar uma ViewModel que contenha os dois ou mais Models.

A ViewModel não deve ter métodos, só propriedades necessárias para a view.
Ai sua view trabalhará com esse ViewModel e seu controller deve fazer todo o trabalho de carregar/descarregar essa ViewModel com os dados dos Models.

Se eu entendi seu exemplo, cada ticket pode ter várias evoluções, então seu ViewModel deve carregar o ticket em questão e uma coleção de suas evoluções.

```
    public class EvolucaoDoTicketViewModel
{
    public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Evolucao> Evolucao { get; set; }
}
```

No seu controller você deve carregar o ticket em questão e a coleção com as evoluções relacionadas com o seu id.

Você poderá trabalhar com esses dados na sua view e depois no controller (em caso de modificar os dados por exemplo) "descarregar" os dados da ViewModel nos models correspondentes e salva-los.

Comment: Olá Fabri, fiz a implementação através do uso de view model como sugerido, porém estou tendo dificuldade em apresentar os dados das evoluções na View. Só consegui fazer isso utilizando o helper GridView. Você conhece alguma forma que eu possa utilizar os HTML Helpers para exibir as informações contidas na coleção Evoluções presentes na ViewModel?